# Image rename error using java

Tags: java, file-upload, file-rename

Here i'm able to change the name of image but for the new image i'm not getting the same image as first one.

Here my initial image is ABC.png and new image is XYZ.png i'm able to change the image name from ABC.png to XYZ.png but i need XYZ.png as similar to ABC.png just i need to change name of image.

Here is my code

```
File prevfile = new File(ImagesPath + "/" + oldvalue + ".png");
File nextfile = new File(ImagesPath + "/" + newValue + ".png");
prevfile.renameTo(nextfile);
```

Comment: Please show the full code.

Comment: You should check if the new file exists already and if the rename operation succeeds (it returns a boolean value).

Comment: i did that but not working

Comment: Yeah, checks are not going to make it work. They might just give you a hint on why it is not working. Have you tried Files.move ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29

Comment: thanks for reply,Could you please tell me where to change the code?

Comment: The doc link I posted explains how to use that method.

Answer (score 0):

File prevfile = new File(ImagesPath + "/" + oldvalue + ".png");

File nextfile = new File(ImagesPath + "/" + newValue + ".png");

//prevfile.renameTo(nextfile);

Rather than renameTo function better use

FileUtils.copyFile(prevfile , nextfile );

prevfile .delete();

Rename Image with new name and delete previous name.